# Haskell Leksah and GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci, leksah

In Leksah, I get the following error whenever trying to debug anything. First it says:

"GHCi debugger is not running."

So I click "Start GHCi"

Then I get the following in the console:

`` GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghc: --interactive can't be used with -prof or -unreg.
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option. ``

My project `cabal builds` fine. I've done everything in my `cabal` and `apt-get` back go tricks to try and get this working. But to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently Leksah is just terrible and unreliable. Don't bother with Leksah, if you want ide style features for Haskell try:

- Fp Complete
- Atom.io with ide-haskell
- Vim
- Emacs

Comment: that's a rather harsh judgment. it looks like someone opened a ticket here, but didn't respond when people tried to help out: https://github.com/leksah/leksah/issues/47

Comment: I stand by it. Leksah was last updated 3 months ago, so bugs are not being addressed in a timely manner.

Comment: I have to agree with @Fresh. I just downloaded Leksah, and it makes 0 sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give Leksah another go. It is pretty nice the latest version, works with ghc 7.10.